# Avoiding initial load for image transform

Tags: image-transforms, plugin-elementapi

I'm using the element API to get the url of an asset from angular with:

```
'image' => $entry->playerImage->first()->getUrl("square"),
```

Problem is until i visit that image in the browser the url doesn't work, does someone know of a nice way of dealing with this?

Comment: I'm actually not sure if this will work from the PHP side or not, so I'm adding it as a comment, but what happens if you set [generateTransformsBeforePageLoad](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#generateTransformsBeforePageLoad) to `true`?

Answer (score 2):

You can tell Craft to generate new image transforms right when [getUrl()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/AssetFileModel#getUrl-detail) is called by setting the [generateTransformsBeforePageLoad](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#generateTransformsBeforePageLoad) config setting to `true`. Assuming you still want the default behavior on your main website, you can set the setting programatically from your endpoint config with [ConfigService::set()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/ConfigService#set-detail):

```php
'endpoint/path' => function() {
    craft()->config->set('generateTransformsBeforePageLoad', true);

    return [
        // ...
    ];
},
```

Comment: would this go in the `general.php` config?

Comment: @seth that code is for Craft 2 and would go in `config/elementapi.php`.